# How to do a GroupBy statement with ServiceStack OrmLite

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I am doing some queries for Data Visualization and rely on GroupBy, Avg, Sum, and similar functions to get a good dataset from the DB.

I would like to use something similar to GroupBy with ServiceStack OrmLite.  On the [ShippersExample page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/ShippersExample.cs) I see the following query.  Is there an easier or better way to do this?

For example, I have a 'location' column and would like to find the top 5 locations of an entry, and list these locations with the amount of times it occurs.  I only have 1 table, so no need for joins.

```
    var rows = db.SqlList<ShipperTypeCount>(
       "SELECT {0}, COUNT(*) AS Total 
       FROM Shippers 
       GROUP BY {0} 
       ORDER BY Total".Fmt("ShipperTypeId".SqlColumn()));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use a `SqlExpression`, e.g:

```
var rows = db.SqlList<ShipperTypeCount>(
    db.From<Shipper>()
    .GroupBy(x => x.ShipperTypeId)
    .OrderBy("Total")
    .Select(x => new { x.ShipperTypeId, Total = Sql.As(Sql.Count("*"), "Total") }));
```

Alternatively instead of using a concrete POCO you can use a generic dictionary to populate a dictionary of `ShipperTypeId => Total`, e.g:

```
var q = db.From<Shipper>()
    .GroupBy(x => x.ShipperTypeId)
    .OrderBy("2")
    .Select(x => new { x.ShipperTypeId, Total = Sql.Count("*") });

var results = db.Dictionary<int, int>(q);
```

Comment: i like the option of returning a dictionary.  Thank you for providing both possibilities in the answer!  :)

Comment: The 2 in the second orderby example...is that the # of the column in the DB?

Comment: The 2 refers to the second item in the new resultset, in this case the count.  Excellent example.